# Remove invalid symbols from a text in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove invalid symbols from a text. I have this code:

```
def parse_documentation(filename):
    filename=open(filename)
    invalidsymbols=["`","~","!", "@","#","$"]
    for lines in filename:
        print(lines)
        for word in lines:
        print(word)
            for letter in word:
                if invalidsymbols==letter:
                    print(letter)
```

First I'm just testing it by printing the letter and then I would add the code to delete it ( del()).I have more invalid symbols than the ones in the list but it's alot so I wanted to check using just 5 or 6. The problem I am having is that it doesn't only print the invalid symbols but it prints all the letters in my text. Also, for some reason it prints extra characters before my text as well. How do I fix that?

The text I'm using is:

```
he's a jolly good fellow#
I want pizza!
I'm driving to school$
```

Comment: That's not how `for` works with strings.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams   How should I access the letter in each line?

Comment: Perhaps you should examine more closely what `for` is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def parse_documentation(filename):
    filename=open(filename, "r") # open file
    lines = filename.read(); # read all the lines in the file to a list named as "lines"
    invalidsymbols=["`","~","!", "@","#","$"]
    for line in lines: # for each line in lines
        for x in invalidsymbols: # loop through the list of invalid symbols
            if x in line: # if the invalid symbols is in the line
                print(line) # print out the line
                print(x) # and also print out the invalid symbol you encountered in that line
                print(line.replace(x, "")) # print out a line with invalid symbol removed
```

How about that ?

Comment: Welcome :) You are still printing the line everytime you encounter an invalid symbol (if the symbol occurs more than once)

Comment: Just added another line in the code, you can simply remove the unwanted character in a string by doing `string.replace(character, "")`

Answer (score 4):

You can remove undesired symbols all at once with `str.translate`:

```
>>> txt = """he's a jolly good fellow#
... I want pizza!
... I'm driving to school$"""
>>> print txt.translate(None, "`~!@#$")
he's a jolly good fellow
I want pizza
I'm driving to school
```

so your code might be something like

```
def parse_documentation(filename, invalid_symbols):
    symb_to_remove = ''.join(invalid_symbols)
    with open(filename, 'rb') as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            safe_line = line.translate(None, symb_to_remove)
            <here comes code to do smthng with safe_line>
```

and you'll call this function with

```
parse_documentation(filename, ["`","~","!", "@","#","$"])
```

Answer (score 0):

JoeC already answered, but I would like to add that if your *invalid* symbols occur more than once in the line, then you are probably better off doing the following

```
def parse_documentation(filename):
    filelines = open(filename)
    invalidsymbols=["`","~","!", "@","#","$"]
    for line in filelines:
        print(lines)
        for symbol in invalidsymbols:
            if symbol in line:
                print("Above line contains %s symbol"%symbol)
```

As for replacing the symbols, refer to [JoeC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20105976/2689986).

Answer (score 0):

Try using **textcleaner** library for this task. 
Follow this link for homepage and documenatation: https://pypi.org/project/textcleaner/ 
Call remove_symbols function and it will return you a clean text. It uses regular expression only. 
Function description:
https://yugantm.github.io/textcleaner/documentation.html#remove_symbols